# Use an LA6500 to increase the current output of an MCP4725

Tags: arduino, voltage, operational-amplifier, current, dac

I am trying to use an [LA6500](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LA6500-D.PDF) to increase the current output from an [MCP4725](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22039d.pdf) that I am controlling with an Arduino UNO.  The LA6500 works well for voltages of 1 to 4 volts but but when I give it 5 volts, the output of the LA6500 is 4.63V.

What should I do to get a 5V output from the LA6500?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need a higher voltage power supply for the [LA6500.](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LA6500-D.PDF)

[image]

The table shows the output range ("Maximum output voltage") when operated from +-15V.  Best case, +-13V.  That difference between supply voltage and output voltage will also hold for lower supply voltages.

The output can't reach the power supply voltage.  It will always "get stuck" a couple of volts below the positive voltage rail, and a couple of volts above the low rail.  With your six volt power supply, the output of the LA6500 can only vary between about 2 volts and 4 volts (give or take a bit.)

You need a higher voltage to get 5V out.

If you need to get below 2V, then you'll need to supply it with a bipolar power supply.

Expressed simply:

The LA6500 doesn't have rail to rail output.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is because of the internal circuitry of the LA6500. You can't get "rail-to-rail" output voltage out of it.

If you look in the datasheet you will find this:
[image]

A crude simulation in a free application like LTSpice of the upper part of the output stage reveals that the output will never be 6V:

[image]

So as JRE mentioned in his answer you need more voltage to the VCC pin of the LA6500 to go above ~4.8V. The lower part of the output stage also has the same limitation, so you might need a bipolar (positive and negative) supply.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I also need 1 and 2 volts in output.I did not work with the bipolar  supply. Can you show me a sample circuit that should be used?

Comment: The basics: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-obtain-negative-voltage-from-a-DC-power-supply-or-battery.php Do a Google search on LM79xx for negative voltage regulators. But first, just increase your positive supply and see if it works alright at 2V-5V input. Then get your negative supply if you find that your 1V input isn't low enough.